# View is passing anonymous type to controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using C# and MVC 5, but for some reason my view is passing an anonymous type back to the controller, and it's not happy about that. The specific error is:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException' occurred in System.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Id'
```

This is the specific controller function signature:

```
[HttpPost, ParameterBasedOnFormName("save-continue", "continueEditing")]
public ActionResult TaskEdit(dynamic model, bool continueEditing)
```

The error occurs when I try to reference `model.Id` in that function. The beginning of the view is this:

```
@model ProjectModelShopModel
// ...
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, Model))
{
    // code
}
```

How do I solve this error? I can provide more code if necessary.

**EDIT:** I use a dynamic type in `TaskEdit` because three views call that function, each with a different model. The function is nearly identical in each. I don't use inheritance because I screwed up too much early on and it would take *way* too much work to fix now.

Comment: why are you using anonymous type?

Comment: you should be passed "ProjectModelShopModel" in the TaskEdit action instead of the "dynamic" type

Comment: Because of the abundant abuse of the word "dynamic" in programming (everything is dynamic), this is hard to research. I **think** the default modelbinder can't really bind to a dynamic model, as it searches for existing properties on the type of the parameter, of which there are none. Try using a `FormCollection collection` as parameter instead to bypass the modelbinder and read the form data yourself. Of course you should strive to create a model that captures the data you want to post, as this makes programming the controller a lot easier.

Comment: I just clarified why I'm using a `dynamic` type in the controller in an edit.

Comment: FWIW, you should almost never type anything `dynamic`. I say almost never because there's exceptions to every rule, but 99.99% of the time I've seen `dynamic` used by developers it's the wrong way to go or simply a sign of laziness.

Comment: @CodeCaster Not sure how to utilize that type. Could you clarify?

Comment: @ChrisPratt I know, I should've used inheritance, but I'm still pretty new to C#/MVC and it confused the hell out of me. It'd be too much work to fix all of it now; I unfortunately don't have time.

Comment: @CodeCaster So... instead of `model.Id` I would need to use `int.Parse(model["CreatedById"])`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352481/mvc-4-dynamic-action-method-argument) confirms (without source) my [guess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32403644/view-is-passing-anonymous-type-to-controller#comment52675580_32403644) that the default modelbinder can't really work with `dynamic` parameters.

The default modelbinder looks for existing properties on the parameter types (of which `dynamic` has very little), and then tries to map the posted fields to those properties.

Workarounds are to use [`public ActionResult TaskEdit(FormCollection formCollection)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4902806/266143) and fill your model in your controller, or to [use a custom modelbinder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6861683/how-can-i-make-a-controller-action-take-a-dynamic-parameter).

Comment: As much extra work as this will cause, would the best option ultimately be to use polymorphism correctly?

Comment: @Vaindil yes, definitely.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense then. `dynamic` has caused me nothing but headaches and I'll have to properly figure out polymorphism at some point, so I'll accept your answer. (Mainly because it does actually answer the question, but also because of your comment.)

Comment: Polymorphism will allow you to share bits of code that operate on the base class, perhaps even use editor templates to reduce form rendering and processing duplication. It's most certainly the way to go, thanks for seeing the light. ;)

Answer (score 2):

It is model binding problem. You are sending a post request to a single method with 3 types of models. That method has to accept that model and expose you the values of that. There are couple of ways to achieve this -

1. Create your own model binder

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]
   ```

CustomModelBinder is an extension of default model binder. You can find the implementation [here](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/ASP-NET-MVC-Dynamic-Model-Binding.aspx)

2. Use Form Collection instead of binding to specific model to get data

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult ActionName(FormCollection formData) 
   {
       var variablename = Request.Form["VariableName"]; 
   }
   ```

You can find the example [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/639709/Getting-Data-From-View-to-Controller-in-MVC)

**Edit** Modified example link for formcollection

Comment: That FormCollection article on c-sharpcorner is really, really crappy. In the first place because he doesn't even use the FormCollection in the code, but it's also full of errors, lacks any explanation and uses archaic pre-razor syntax.